# Getting custom properties of a generic object

Tags: c#, object, properties

I've got a method that returns a list of objects.

```
List<object> messageList = queueQuery.GetMessageCollection();

foreach (object message in messageList)
{
    string contentType = message.ContentType
}
```

It doesn't really matter, but the type of these objects happens to be (for now anyway) Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.  However, in the class where I'm working, I don't want it to be dependent on Microsoft.ServiceBus. Separation of concerns.

The class which houses queueQuery.GetMessageCollection() IS dependent on Microsoft.ServiceBus, but in case we ever want to use another message queue system, I want it so that the worker class which processes the messages is unaware of what type of message it is.

That being said, I need access to some of the properties of these objects.  This screen shot is from the worker class that will process the messages.  I need to get the ContentType.  But, of course, when I try this:

```
string contentType = message.ContentType
```

I get: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ContentType'. It IS there. I can see it in the watch.  But.. How do I access this property?

[image]

Comment: "It doesn't really matter" --> it does to the compiler...

Comment: It sounds like you have more of a dependency on this particular message queue system than you'd like to admit.  You're uncomfortable with the worker class knowing what type of message it is, but you're comfortable requiring that class to have a `string` field named `ContentType`?

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is:  If I can see it in the watch, it must be accessible.  Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

1. Create an interface that contains the properties you expect from *any* object passed in.  Return a list of that interface type instead of `List<object>`.  Create a wrapper class to pass the properties from `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage` through as necessary.  More work, but compile-time safe.
2. Use `dynamic` instead of `object`.  The danger is that you defer all binding to runtime, so if something passes in an object that doesn't have a `ContentType` property you won't know it until run-time.  Less work (lazy), more danger of hard-to-debug run-time errors.
3. Use reflection.  Same danger as dynamic, and more code, but with more capability to detect objects that don't have the properties you expect and handle them gracefully.

Comment: Ok, yeah, I was kinda thinking along the lines of option #1, but was hoping to avoid it.  Thanks.